# Scheduling Crystal Reports to run automatically

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, business-objects, crystal-reports-2010

I am currently working on a ASP.NET 4.0 / .NET 4.0 project using Crystal Reports version 13.

The reports has a start date and end date as paramter and I am able to render the reports that are hosted on business objects server.

Is there way to schedule the report to run automatically? I have never done a scheduled crystal report and I am looking for options. I appreciate your support!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have use this free software [Crystal Delivery](http://www.groffautomation.com/) in past job. works fine